# Does this limit exist

Tags: calculus, limits

Does this limit exist and is finite?
(It goes to one from the left

$\lim_{x\to 1^-}{{(\ln(x) \times \ln(x)}})$

Comment: Since $\ln x$ is continuous at $x = 1$, the limit is simply zero.

Comment: Seems like I didn't write the correct limit. Notice the ln(ln(x))

Comment: I called a rollback.  You should [ask a new question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/25490/290189) then.

Answer (score 4):

The function is defined $(0,\infty)$, continuous and derivable... Why would not exist?

$$\ln(1) = 0  \rightarrow \lim_{x \rightarrow 1^{-}}{\ln(x)\cdot \ln(x)} = 0 \cdot 0 = 0 $$

Comment: It wasn't the limit I intended. The new one is updated

Comment: Please ignore the previous comment.  I've [called a rollback](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/25490/290189) since such an edit had rendered an existing answer *wrong*.

Answer (score 2):

The function $\ln^2(x)$ is continuous at 1, therefore the limit exists and

$$0=\ln^2(1)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\ln^2(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^-}\ln^2(x)$$

Comment: Seems like I didn't write the correct limit. I changed it

Comment: Please ignore the previous comment. I've [called a rollback](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/25490/290189) since such an edit had rendered an existing answer wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The function is nowhere defined for $x\le1$, so no.

Comment: Sorry, I called a rollback.  In the edit history of this question, we see that OP changed his question in a significant way that had rendered other existing answers invalid.  In this case, I [called a rollback](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/25490/290189).